# Office 2010 Pro Plus Install Failure - Setup cannot find ProPlusr.WW\ProPrWW2.cab

Tags: installation, microsoft-office-2010

I'm attempting to install Office 2010 Pro Plus on a netbook running WWindows 7 Starter but the installer prompts for a file location:

*Setup cannot find ProPlusr.WW\ProPrWW2.cab. Browse to a valid installation source, and then click OK.*

I checked the installation files and can see that the file is present. I selected the folder and clicked OK, but the installer keeps prompting for the file.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Comment: That file is probably corrupt. Check if there are scratches on your CD. If so you may need to get a replacement medium or download the .cab from Internet. I am not sure if the latter method is legal though.

Comment: Thanks bill.cn - got another copy of the installer and it worked fine. Must have been a corruption somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Is there any trial or multiple versions of Office installed on the system?If present Uninstall them. And try to extract the file and then try to install:

- Click on Start > All Programs > Accessories > Run
- Click on the Office installation executable file and drag and drop it
  into the ‘Run’ command to get the file name and its location in the
  ‘Run’ command's open tab.
- Go to the run command > press ‘End’ button on the keyboard > press
  the ‘Space’ key > type ‘/extract’ without quotes > OK Example:
  C:\Users.....OfficeSetup.exe /extract
- You will be prompted to store extracted files, Click on Desktop > Make a
  new folder > name the folder as ‘Office Setup’
- Wait until the file extraction completes > Open the ‘Office Setup’
  folder from desktop.
- Double click on Setup file and try installing the Office suite.

Comment: For me the `/extract` gives an error that gives the possibilities to use with the setup run and *extract* isn't one of the options. `setup controller command-line help`.